# How to calculate this series about expectation?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

How to calculate this series $$\sum_{z=0}^\infty z\cdot p^8(1-p)^z\cdot{z+7\choose 7}$$ where p is a real number and $0<p<1$

In fact, this is a expectation $\mathbf{E}(z)$ with the pmf $p_z(z) = p^8(1-p)^z\cdot{z+7 \choose 7}$. I've been working on it for long time without any process. Any hint is helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Show: $$z\binom{z+7}7=8\binom{z+7}{8}.$$

Comment: Your random variable possesses a $\text{NB}(8,1-p)$ distribution which you can see here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, notice that for $z\neq 0$
$$
z{z+r-1 \choose r-1} = r{z+r-1 \choose r}
$$
Now define $x=z-1$ then
$$
r{x+r\choose r} = \frac{(x+r)!}{r! x!} = (-1)^{x}\frac{(-(x+r))\cdots(-(r+1))}{x!} = (-1)^{x}{-(r+1)\choose x}
$$
In the expectation function
$$
\mathbb{E}Z = rp^{r}(1-p)\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}{-(r+1)\choose x}(-(1-p))^{x}
$$
Using that (yes, it also holds for negative numbers) $(1+a)^{\alpha}=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}{\alpha\choose x}a^{x}$ we have
$$
\mathbb{E}Z = rp^{r}(1-p)\left(1-(1-p)\right)^{r+1} = \frac{r(1-p)}{p}
$$
Which is the expected value of a negative binomial distribution, so it coincides with the pmf you were working with.

**Easier way**
As a side note, recall that a negative binomial with parameters $r$ and $p$ is the sum of $r$ $iid$ random variables with Geometric distribution with parameter $p$. Since the expectation of a Geometric RV is $\frac{p}{1-p}$ then the expected value of the NB is $\frac{rp}{1-p}$. In your case, you have flipped $p$ and $1-p$ but everything still holds.